# Need to separate strings into multiple variables based on numeric versus non-numeric

Tags: r, gsub, strsplit

I have a data frame with one variable. It looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c("25 Edgemont 52 Sioux County", "57 Burke 88 Papillion-LaVista South"))
```

To provide more context, each observation/row is a basketball game score. I would like to separate into four data frame columns that splits the numbers and team names up. So for example, the first row would end up as "25" in first column, "Edgemont" in second column, "52" in third column, and Sioux City in fourth column.

I've tried the below and various SO suggestions but can't get the desired results:

```
df2 <- strsplit(gsub("([0-9]*)([a-z]*)([0-9]*)([a-z]*)", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", df), " ")
```

Comment: Try `library(stringr)` and then `str_extract_all(df[[1]], "\\d+|[^\\d\\s](?:\\D*[^\\d\\s])?")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** Replace each number with a semicolon, that number and another semicolon and then separate on the semicolons plus optional surrounding whitespace.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# input
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("25 Edgemont 52 Sioux County", 
                        "57 Burke 88 Papillion-LaVista South"))

df %>%
  mutate(V1 = gsub("(\\d+)", ";\\1;", V1)) %>%
  separate(V1, c(NA, "No1", "Let1", "No2", "Let2"), sep = " *; *")
##   No1       Let1 No2                     Let2
## 1  25  Edgemont   52             Sioux County
## 2  57     Burke   88  Papillion-LaVista South
```

**1a) read.table**  We can use the same `gsub` as in (1) but then separate it using `read.table`. No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = gsub("(\\d+)", ";\\1;", df$V1), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE,
  strip.white = TRUE, col.names = c(NA, "No1", "Let1", "No2", "Let2"))[-1]
##   No1     Let1 No2                    Let2
## 1  25 Edgemont  52            Sioux County
## 2  57    Burke  88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

**2) strcapture**  We can use `strcapture` from base R:

```
proto <- list(No1 = integer(0), Let1 = character(0),
              No2 = integer(0), Let2 = character(0))
strcapture("(\\d+) (.*) (\\d+) (.*)", df$V1, proto)
##   No1     Let1 No2                    Let2
## 1  25 Edgemont  52            Sioux County
## 2  57    Burke  88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

**2a) read.pattern** We can use read.pattern with the same pattern as in (2):

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = format(df$V1), pattern = "(\\d+) (.*) (\\d+) (.*)", 
  col.names = c("No1", "Let1", "No2", "Let2"), as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
##   No1     Let1 No2                    Let2
## 1  25 Edgemont  52            Sioux County
## 2  57    Burke  88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

Comment: #1 (dplyr/tidyr/mutate/gsub) worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** One option is `extract` from `tidyr` where we extract one or more digits (`(\\d+)`) at the start (`^`) of the string as a capture group, followed by a space, then one ore more characters that are letters with space, followed by a space, then one or more digits in a capture group, followed by space and rest of the characters as the 4th column

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  extract(col1, into = str_c('col', 1:4),
           '^(\\d+) ([A-Za-z ]+) (\\d+) (.*)', convert  = TRUE)
#  col1     col2 col3                    col4
#1   25 Edgemont   52            Sioux County
#2   57    Burke   88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

---

**2)** Or with `separate` from `tidyr` where we specify a regex lookaround to  split at the space

```
df %>% 
   separate(col1, into = str_c('col', 1:4), sep = '(?<=\\d) | (?=\\d)')
#  col1     col2 col3                    col4
#1   25 Edgemont   52            Sioux County
#2   57    Burke   88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

---

**3)** Or using `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(col1, "(?<=\\d) | (?=\\d)", perl = TRUE)]
#   V1       V2 V3                      V4
#1: 25 Edgemont 52            Sioux County
#2: 57    Burke 88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

---

**4)** Or using `read.csv` from `base R` (No packages are used ...)

```
read.csv(text = gsub("(?<=\\d) | (?=\\d)", ",", df$col1, 
          perl = TRUE), header = FALSE)
#  V1       V2 V3                      V4
#1 25 Edgemont 52            Sioux County
#2 57    Burke 88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

---

**5)** Or with `strsplit` from `base R` (No packages are used ...)

```
type.convert(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
   strsplit(as.character(df$col1), "(?<=\\d) | (?=\\d)",
           perl = TRUE))), as.is = TRUE)
#  V1       V2 V3                      V4
#1 25 Edgemont 52            Sioux County
#2 57    Burke 88 Papillion-LaVista South
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("25 Edgemont 52 Sioux County", 
             "57 Burke 88 Papillion-LaVista South"))
```